# Set a maximum height for background-image but with horizontal cover

Tags: html, css, background-image

I want to add a background image to my page, covering horizontally, but having a height limit.

The problem is that if I set a height, looks like I can't set to cover horizontally. I understand that if covering horizontally, and having a height limit, the bottom part will be clipped (if working).

I'm using cover to avoid distorting the image.

```css
.has-background {
    background-size: cover; /*I want to limit to 200px*/
    background-position: 50%;
    background-image: url("https://picsum.photos/id/430/1230/500");
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bulma/0.9.0/css/bulma.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div id="app" class="has-background">
   <div class="hero is-medium">
       <div class="hero-body>
            <p class="subtitle has-text-centered">Subtitle</p>    
       </div>
   </div>
   
   <div class="hero">
      <div class="hero-body>
           <p class="subtitle has-text-centered">Subtitle</p>  
           <p class="subtitle has-text-centered">Subtitle</p>  
           <p class="subtitle has-text-centered">Subtitle</p>  
           <p class="subtitle has-text-centered">Subtitle</p>  
           <p class="subtitle has-text-centered">Subtitle</p>  
           <p class="subtitle has-text-centered">Subtitle</p>  
           <p class="subtitle has-text-centered">Subtitle</p>  
           <p class="subtitle has-text-centered">Subtitle</p>  
           <p class="subtitle has-text-centered">Subtitle</p>  
           <p class="subtitle has-text-centered">Subtitle</p>  
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Is there any way to set a height to the background-image while covering horizontally the viewport (and without needing to have a new element with `position: fixed`)?

Comment: I don't understand if you are willing to use height: 200px for the div, or why not

Comment: I'm guessing you don't want to `position: absolute` another `<div class="has-background"></div>` with the background as well or only `position: fixed`?

Comment: My content will take more than 200px of height to be displayed. I wished to set a cover image to be displayed at the top.

Comment: @ChewySalmon That's what I ended up using, but I was thinking if it's possible to be more succinct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A pseudo element can easily do this:

```css
.has-background {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
}

.has-background::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 100%;
  max-height: 200px;
  background-image: url("https://picsum.photos/id/430/1230/500");
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bulma/0.9.0/css/bulma.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div id="app" class="has-background">
  <div class="hero is-medium">
    <div class="hero-body">
      <p class="subtitle has-text-centered">Subtitle</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="hero">
    <div class="hero-body">
      <p class="subtitle has-text-centered">Subtitle</p>
      <p class="subtitle has-text-centered">Subtitle</p>
      <p class="subtitle has-text-centered">Subtitle</p>
      <p class="subtitle has-text-centered">Subtitle</p>
      <p class="subtitle has-text-centered">Subtitle</p>
      <p class="subtitle has-text-centered">Subtitle</p>
      <p class="subtitle has-text-centered">Subtitle</p>
      <p class="subtitle has-text-centered">Subtitle</p>
      <p class="subtitle has-text-centered">Subtitle</p>
      <p class="subtitle has-text-centered">Subtitle</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Nice. Can't we remove the `.has-background` properties and shove them into the `::before`?

Comment: @NickeManarin yes it's surely allowed

Answer (score 0):

You can set height on `.has-background` class so it will fix the height of your container element & keep the width 100% as div is a block element.

```css
.has-background {
    background-size: 100% 200px; /*I want to limit to 200px*/
    background-position: fixed;
    background-image: url("https://picsum.photos/id/430/1230/500");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bulma/0.9.0/css/bulma.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div id="app" class="has-background">
   <div class="hero is-medium">
       <div class="hero-body>
            <p class="subtitle has-text-centered">Subtitle</p>    
       </div>
   </div>
   
   <div class="hero">
      <div class="hero-body>
           <p class="subtitle has-text-centered">Subtitle</p>  
           <p class="subtitle has-text-centered">Subtitle</p>  
           <p class="subtitle has-text-centered">Subtitle</p>  
           <p class="subtitle has-text-centered">Subtitle</p>  
           <p class="subtitle has-text-centered">Subtitle</p>  
           <p class="subtitle has-text-centered">Subtitle</p>  
           <p class="subtitle has-text-centered">Subtitle</p>  
           <p class="subtitle has-text-centered">Subtitle</p>  
           <p class="subtitle has-text-centered">Subtitle</p>  
           <p class="subtitle has-text-centered">Subtitle</p>  
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, that limits my content. I only want to limit the `background-image`.

Comment: @NickeManarin you can use background-size property for that, just write like this background-size: 100% 200px; that's it.

Comment: @NickeManarin check now, i have edited above example.

Answer (score -2):

You can use css property

```
max-height: px;
```

Here is a [documentation](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_max-height.asp)

Comment: Hi, that limits my content. I only want to limit the `background-image`.